# Regenerate random number in for loop if a certain condition isn't met in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have this loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $random_number = rand(1, 9);

    if (!in_array($section_one, $random_number)) {
        array_push($section_one, rand(1, 9));
    }
}
```

As you can see the if statement in the loop checks if the generated random number is already in the array called $section_one. The problem is that if the random number *is* in the array, a new random number should be generated. Doing this ones is easy, but it has to keep regenerating a random number until a unique one has been generated.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
$run = true;
$max = 9;
$section_one = [];

while ($run) {
    $rand = rand(1,$max);
    if(!in_array($rand, $section_one)){
        array_push($section_one, $rand);   
    }
    if(count($section_one) >= $max) $run =  false;
}
```

The idea is running loop until `$section_one` got full unique numbers.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
$section_one = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
    $random_number = rand(1, 9);

    if (!in_array($random_number,$section_one)) {
        array_push($section_one, $random_number);
    }
}
var_dump($section_one);
```